# Prevent temporally suspend/hibernate from script?

Tags: power-management, suspend, hibernate, scripts, ftp

Is there any way to prevent temporally suspend/hibernate from a script?

I want the screen to enter in powersave mode when appropriate, but the computer doesn't stop. 
`Caffeine` doesn't allow this: it disables all or nothing.

Why I want to do this? Because sometimes I download huge amount of files from a server via FTP. These downloads can take hours to complete.

Comment: See this(http://askubuntu.com/questions/576525/can-i-prevent-ubuntu-being-suspended-while-a-download-is-in-progress) question. You can use the script provided there to supersede suspend while any upload or download in progress. Change wlan0 to eth0 or use both if its applies.

Answer (score 6):

To prvent hibernation, create `/var/run/do-not-hibernate`:

```
sudo touch /var/run/do-not-hibernate
```

The file `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change` makes this work. If you need to disable suspend, create a new file for that, say `/etc/pm/sleep.d/000_prevent_suspend_hibernate`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Prevents the machine from suspending or hibernating when
# the file /var/run/do-not-hibernate-or-suspend exist
case "$1" in
  suspend|hibernate)
    [ -f /var/run/do-not-hibernate-or-suspend ] && exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/000_prevent_suspend_hibernate
```

In case you need to prevent the machine from suspending or hibernating, create a file:

```
sudo touch /var/run/do-not-hibernate-or-suspend
```

After rebooting or removing this file, suspending and hibernating works again.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test your script with a little change. Instead of create the file `/var/run/do-not-hibernate-or-suspend`, I'll test the existence of a lftp process active with "`pidof lftp`".

Comment: It doesn't work. I think these scripts aren't used. Because the pm-suspend.log shows lines like: "`/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/...`". I'll test moving the script to this folder: `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/`

Comment: I thought that `exit 1` would stop the hibernate process but it doesn't.
I'm testing now with: `. "${PM_FUNCTIONS}"
...   pidof lftp && inhibit`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a file to `/etc/pm/sleep.d`
In this file do you checks if suspend should be allowed. If not just exit with `exit 1`.

For example:

```
tmp_start=...
tmp_stop=...

if [ $((tmp_stop)) -gt $((current_date)) -a $((tmp_start)) -lt $((current_date)) ]; then
    logger $0: Currently RECORDING. No Suspend!
    exit 1;
fi
```