# how to prevent the computer from going into sleep mode when data is being read over ethernet?

Tags: suspend, samba, network-monitoring

I use my desktop as a file server for music which plays on my `Sonos` system. Now, after the computer hasn't been in use for time `X`, it will go to standby/sleep mode and thus, the music will stop. Now I was wondering if there's a way to prevent the computer from going to sleep if let's say a particular bandwith in egress direction is active on `eth0`? 
So that I can  keep my sleep settings if the computer is not being used (and no music is playing).

Comment: Change the power settings from system settings. Change the `suspend when inactive` option values to `Don't suspend`

Comment: I want to keep my sleep settings if the computer is not being used!

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here...

[Is there any way to make Ubuntu not to suspend while a download in progress?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576525/is-there-any-way-to-make-ubuntu-not-to-suspend-while-a-download-in-progress/673354#673354)

Its a program I wrote to sort out the exact same problem and more.  In my case I was serving to Kodi and DLNA devices videos, pictures and music; also when doing backups to another server.

It also solves the problem of running a program unattended over a period of time.

Launchpad link here:

https://launchpad.net/keep.awake